# Receiving an error about unable to copy from graph.edges to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am unable to create an empty dataframe and then copy the edge nodes into the dataframe using a list comprehension.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Source','Target'])
df[['Source','Target']] = [(s,t) for (s,t) in graph.edges]
```

I receive an error stating that it can't copy 44000 into a series.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno what graph edges are and I don't want to guess. This code has the same problem.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Source','Target'])
df[['Source','Target']] = [(s,t) for (s,t) in zip(range(1000), range(1000))]
```

Results in:

`ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 1000 to array axis with dimension 0`

I don't really have an answer for why besides you just can't do that.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Source','Target'])
df[['Source','Target']] = pd.DataFrame([(s,t) for (s,t) in zip(range(1000), range(1000))])
```

Now it works.

```
>>> df.head()
   Source  Target
0       0       0
1       1       1
2       2       2
3       3       3
4       4       4
```